# Does upsell or cross sell decrease conversion?

Tags: e-commerce, conversion

Let's say I have a product page with accessories, and a checkout page. I want to include a another group of accessories that this user can add to cart on their way out. It's a candy aisle, basically. Do you think it would be good to include this candy aisle on the right rail of the checkout page, as long as there are NO LINKS to other pages, only ADD TO CART links? This way, I won't interrupt the checkout process, but it's easy for the user to add more things on their way out? Do you think this setup would hurt conversion in any way?

What about a scenario where it flowed from "Product Page" to "Offer of a better product at a slightly higher price" to "Checkout"? How many people would you lose a conversion to by inserting that Offer?

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like a good opportunity for A/B testing - try all these variations and see which one gets the best results for the site's particular products and customers.

Comment: Very valid point about AB testing, however that's really the answer to a different question. If the question were *'how to identify if cross-selling decreases conversions'* this would be ideal, but your answer itself doesn't really answer whether or not cross-selling impacts conversion.

Answer (score 0):

By checkout page do you mean the page prior to starting the checkout process - the page that tells you what you are about to buy (often but not always the bag / basket / cart / trolley)?

If so then upselling at this point is fairly common and is something I have played with myself. Consider linking the items to the items that are in the basket - this would increase the likelihood of up-sell in theory. It's also okay to include links to pages providing the existing items are already in the basket and there is a clear way to return back to complete the process.

A/B or multivariant testing (MVT) as mentioned by britta is a good way to test an idea once it's had a good degree of thought and research put into it. It's a way to double check before sending it to a wider audience and is best for final tests rather than design by trial and error.

Once in the checkout process the standard approach is to remove everything distracting till they get to the end - at which point you can then tell them about other stuff and maybe get them to buy something else again as they've already bought some things.

All this depends on the type of items you're selling of course - for a fashion site upselling at all points would be overkill for example.